# Converting nullable object values to strings in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, jsx

A little stuck trying to get the response from a GraphQL API typed properly so that I can use it with forms.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because React inputs expect values to be strings and not null. So I need to convert my nullable fields to empty strings before passing them on to the JSX.

This is a bit of a contrived case but should give the gist.

```
Interface IApiResult {
    title: string;
    description: string | null;
}

// I would expect this to have the shape { title: string, description: string }
//
type NonNullApiResult<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: string
}

// API result
const result: IApiResult = { title: 'SO TS question', description: null }

// Mapped API result where all values must be strings
const mappedResult: NonNullApiResult<IApiResult> = {
    title: '',
    description: ''
}

// HERE: How can these be merged so that `mappedResult` stays
// of type NonNullApiResult and the data looks like:
//
// mappedResult = { title: 'SO TS question', 'description': '' }
```

*I tried this..*

```
// Loop through the result and convert null fields to empty strings
for (const key in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        // `value` is being given the type "any".
        // I would expect it to be "string | null"
        const value = result[key]

        // This passes. I'm guessing because `value` is "any"
        // However, it will still pass the null value into `mappedResult`
        // I would expect this to fail w/ "null not assignable to string"
        mappedResult[key] = value

        // This what I would expect to do
        // mappedResult[key] = value === null ? '' : value
    }
}
```

`mappedResult` is still of type `NonNullApiResult<IApiResult>` but if I `console.log(mappedResult)` I get the this in the browser:

`{description: null, title: 'SO TS question'}`

If I then do something in React like this it passes because it thinks `description` is a string

```
<input name="description" id="description" type="text" value={mappedResult.description} />
```

But in the console I get the expected error:

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated! This is using Typescript version 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function mapData(data){
  const mappedResult = {};
  for (const key in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      mappedResult[key] = result[key] || "";
    }
  }
  return mappedResult;
}
```

It should check each key in object, and if it is a falsy one (null || undefined) assign it an empty string.

And to clarify some more - what is `i` variable?

Comment: Sorry the `i` variable was a typo. Meant to use `value`. Updated the original question.

Comment: I tried your snippet but it seemed to suffer from the same issues I was originally running into. Where incorrect types can be assigned to `mappedResult` props.

(Slightly modified to not be wrapped in a func)


    `for (const key in result) {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            mappedResult[key] = result[key] || 1
        }
    }`.

I would expect that loop to fail just as `mappedResult.description = 1` does, but it still passes and `description` incorrectly ends up with a number and not string